# About the Convex Hull of a the image of a function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, convolution, convex-hulls

Let $ f \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R^n)$ and $ \varphi $ a mollifier, consider $\varphi_{\varepsilon}:=\frac{1}{\varepsilon ^n} \varphi \left( \frac{x}{\varepsilon} \right)$ show that $f * \varphi_{\varepsilon}(E)$ is contained in the closed convex hull of $f(E)$, $\forall E \subset \mathbb R^n$

I try to use some properties of the convolution like continuity, but i not sure if these is correct, i not have idea can procedure in these problem.

Any hint or help i will be very grateful

Comment: $f(E)$ is not a well defined set since $L^{1}_{loc}$ consists of equivalence classes of functions.

Comment: @geetha290krm then these problem is wrong?

Comment: @NickWeber  Yes, the question is wrong. If $f$ is  a real valued locally integrable function we can always redefine it on a countable subset of $E$  to make convex hull of $f(E)$ equal to $\mathbb R$ in which case there is nothing to prove.